# How did the terms "center" and "centralizer" come up in group theory?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Usually the word *center* means the center of a circle. I have encountered the word *center* in group theory, but do not see any connection with the *center* of a circle. I think the history of group theory probably has something to do with it.

Can anyone tell me how the terms **[center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory))** and **centralizer** came up in group theory?

I have searched for "center in group theory" here, but it was not previously asked, and did not get anything from the web either.

Comment: The English usage of **center** of a group presumably is merely a translation of the German **Zentrum**.  But that merely moves the question to the reason for the German terminology.  I looked in my old German copy of van der Waerden, but he give no reason for the term Zentrum.

Comment: We denote the center of a group Z(G) precisely because it came from German practice.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3075020/10513

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The center (originally the [*central*](http://emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?40.0188.01)) seems to have appeared between the first and second edition of Burnside’s book ([1897, §53](https://archive.org/stream/117768378#page/62) vs. [1911, §93](https://books.google.com/books?id=rGMGAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA120)) and more precisely in **de Séguier** ([1904, §51](https://archive.org/stream/thoriedesgroup00sguoft#page/57)):

> Ainsi l’ensemble des éléments normaux de $\mathrm G$ est un diviseur normal qui sera dit *central* de $\mathrm G$.

([Jahrbuch](http://emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?36.0187.02): “Die Gesamtheit invarianter Elemente einer Gruppe nennt Verf. le central der Gruppe.”)

Neither gives an explanation. Guess: conjugacy classes are the orbits of the group’s conjugation action on itself, and a (Kepler) orbit is a point iff it lies at the center. (Then again, maybe they meant the kind of [central](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_telef%C3%B4nica) where operators are busy [commuting](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309857/why-are-commutative-diagrams-called-commutative#comment772034_309857)?)

Comment: Was Frobenius using "center" in his 1887 proof of Sylow theorems? I can't figure out from [Nicholson's paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81931711.pdf), p.79.

Comment: @Conifold [Looking at it](https://archive.org/stream/journalfrdierei15crelgoog#page/n190), it seems not...

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3075020/10513